# SEO - How to programmatically check if a website has been Banned by Google

Tags: seo, pagerank, blacklist

if your website links to another site that has been blacklisted by Google this is bad for your ranking
Sites like [onlinealley](http://onlinealley.com/seotools/googlebannedchecker/) helps you to know if there're problems with a website you are linking to.
Does any Google API Exist .. or how are websites like this checking if a url is banned?
Are they checking the 'PageRank value' or something else?
Thanks

Comment: Forgive my naive question, but if you're only linking to websites that you find great because you want to encourage people to go there, what's the likelihood that any of these sites is google-blacklisted? If you find yourself linking to banned websites... why not tackle the problem at the root and stop linking crap?

Comment: Simply because the content of my website can be dynamically generated. Users can enter links as well. i.e. I'd like to check that all the entered URLs are not linking to blacklisted websites. What about having 5000 users, on their public profile they can point to their own personal website. A way to don't have to manually check if a site is banned will be helpful I think...

Comment: Slap `nofollow` on the links in user generated content, then you don't need to worry about it (and you encourage spammers yes).

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to check for a banned website. There're other use-cases where I can generate text and add links. I want to actually link to websites and I'm not considering the nofollow option.. what I'm asking is not how to block spam. but how to programmatically check the validity of a url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the *nofollow* suggestion. Its what SO does. Take a look at the page source.

You could also maybe do a 'site:PLACE_URL_HERE' lookup on Google to see if it actually returns any pages.

Also have you looked at the [Google Safe Browsing API](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/)? Looks like that might be what your after.

Comment: I don't even have a website that allows users to enter URL. It was only an example. I can imagine that nofollow can be good. My question is how to check for a banned site - not how to prevent spam o bad links

Comment: Did you look at the Google Safe Browsing API?

Answer (score 1):

A banned page has no-cache.

Comment: thx for your response. what does it mean? I can use no-cache to say the browser to don't cache what I'm serving. How is this related to a website that has been banned?

Comment: You check Google if stores cache for that domain, do a query like `cache:stackoverflow.com` this will return output or tell there is no cache. If there is no cache that domain is banned.

Comment: can't a developer just instruct google to don't cache a page? this doesn't mean that the website is bad, doesn't it?

Comment: I haven't heard of this stuff so far. Anyway if you run `cache:domain.com` it will list all pages cached from that domain. There will be at least one page cached somewhere, nobody blocks the entire content of his domain.

Answer (score 0):

Checking cache is good advice but Banned site might have cache for awhile after the ban.

Cross examine data like

- PR score (if banned PR=0)
- Results for site:domain.com Google search (if banned nothing will appear)
- Check cache (if banned no cache will be available)

If 2 or more provide positive indication of ban, then you've been banned. 
(unless it`s a new, yet to be, indexed domain)

Also you should sign up in WMT (Web Master Tools) and if you get banned you might receive this notification: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35665

Hope this helps.

Comment: What tools are you using to check PR, also I got a website which shows 0 which I  have checked using different tools online, not sure if they are reliable, so Im not sure if its banned. the site link is http://mobilebrowbar.com build it for someone.